# Display data from multiple tables in Oracle in one line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got 3 tables as follows:

**table_teams** (*id_team*, name, city)

**table_matches** (*id_match*, date_of_match, city)

**table_game** (*id*, id_team (FK), id_match (FK), goals) -- this one is a junction table between the first two

The same match is introduced into table_game as two separate records, one for each team with its number of goals, but having the same id_match,

```
INSERT INTO table_game(id_team, id_match, goals) VALUES('GER', 1234, 7);
INSERT INTO table_game(id_team, id_match, goals) VALUES('BRA', 1234, 1);
```

and as a single record into table_matches,

```
INSERT INTO table_matches(id_match, date_of_match, city)
VALUES (1234, '8-JUL-2014', 'Belo Horizonte');
```

Now, I would like to create a view that selects data from these tables and displays it as follows:

> Date | Team1 | Goals1 | Goals2 | Team2 | City

The best I managed to do so far is display each record on separate lines in the table.

```
SELECT tm.date_of_match, tt.name, tg.goals, tm.city
FROM table_matches tm, table_teams tt, table_game tg
WHERE tm.id_match = tg.id_match AND tt.id_team = tg.id_team;
```

But I have no idea how to display data as stated above. All my tries resulted in a big mess.

Will appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to join to tbl_game twice once for each team  perhaps for Home vs Away.  but I can't see how you'd tell that. or join so that the id_team with the lower value is always first...

Comment: Side note: your model doesn't have a way to differentiate team1 vs team2 (usually the "home" team and "visitor" team in a lot of sports). If you want your selection to be deterministic you'll have to add some form of sorting to always select in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using JOIN syntax

```
-- Test data
WITH table_game(ID, id_team, id_match, goals) AS (
         SELECT 10, 'USA',  100, 5 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 11, 'RUS',  100, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 12, 'BRA',  100, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 20, 'ARG', 1234, 7 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 21, 'BRA', 1234, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 30, 'ENG', 4321, 6 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 31, 'FRA', 4321, 2 FROM dual
         )
,table_matches(id_match, date_of_match, city) AS (
         SELECT 1234, DATE '2014-07-08', 'Belo Horizonte' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 4321, DATE '2014-08-09', 'Sao Paulo'      FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT  100, DATE '2014-09-10', 'Brasilia'       FROM dual)
,table_teams(id_team, NAME, city) AS (
         SELECT 'ARG', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'BRA', 'Brazil', 'Sao Paulo'       FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ENG', 'England', 'London'         FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'FRA', 'France', 'Paris'           FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'RUS', 'Russia', 'Moscow'          FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'USA', 'United States', 'New York' FROM dual)
-- End Test data
,match_teams AS (
  SELECT id_match, MAX(id_team) team1, MIN(id_team) team2
  FROM   table_game
  GROUP  BY  id_match
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- any valid match should have only 2 teams, otherwise ignored 
)
SELECT M.date_of_match, t1.NAME team1, g1.goals goals1, t2.NAME team2, g2.goals goals2, M.city city_match 
FROM table_matches M
  JOIN match_teams mt ON mt.id_match = M.id_match
  JOIN table_game  g1 ON g1.id_match = M.id_match AND g1.id_team = mt.team1
  JOIN table_game  g2 ON g2.id_match = M.id_match AND g2.id_team = mt.team2
  JOIN table_teams  t1 ON t1.id_team = mt.team1
  JOIN table_teams  t2 ON t2.id_team = mt.team2
/
```

### Joins on WHERE clause

```
-- Test data
WITH table_game(ID, id_team, id_match, goals) AS (
         SELECT 10, 'USA',  100, 5 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 11, 'RUS',  100, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 12, 'BRA',  100, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL -- error (3 records for same match)
         SELECT 20, 'ARG', 1234, 7 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 21, 'BRA', 1234, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 30, 'ENG', 4321, 6 FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 31, 'FRA', 4321, 2 FROM dual
         )
,table_matches(id_match, date_of_match, city) AS (
         SELECT 1234, DATE '2014-07-08', 'Belo Horizonte' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 4321, DATE '2014-08-09', 'Sao Paulo'      FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT  100, DATE '2014-09-10', 'Brasilia'       FROM dual)
,table_teams(id_team, NAME, city) AS (
         SELECT 'ARG', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'BRA', 'Brazil', 'Sao Paulo'       FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ENG', 'England', 'London'         FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'FRA', 'France', 'Paris'           FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'RUS', 'Russia', 'Moscow'          FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'USA', 'United States', 'New York' FROM dual)
-- End Test data
,match_teams AS (
  SELECT id_match, MAX(id_team) team1, MIN(id_team) team2
  FROM   table_game
  GROUP  BY  id_match
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- any valid match should have only 2 teams, otherwise ignored 
)
SELECT M.date_of_match, t1.NAME team1, g1.goals goals1, t2.NAME team2, g2.goals goals2, M.city city_match 
FROM   table_matches M
      ,match_teams mt 
      ,table_game  g1
      ,table_game  g2
      ,table_teams  t1
      ,table_teams  t2
WHERE  mt.id_match = M.id_match
 AND   g1.id_match = M.id_match 
 AND   g1.id_team = mt.team1
 AND   g2.id_match = M.id_match 
 AND   g2.id_team = mt.team2
 AND   t1.id_team = mt.team1
 AND   t2.id_team = mt.team2
/
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. It worked like a charm. 
Our DB course here at my school only covered instructions such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and other similar. I had no idea about JOIN, just looked up its documentation online.
Secondly, could you just tell me if it is possible to replace the id_team that is got for team1 and team2 with the name of that team, using a SELECT instruction?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much!

Comment: Although I recommend using JOIN syntax, I've added a new version avoiding it for you to clarify. Both queries are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROW_NUMBER to assign a value then join against it, something like this:

```
;with cte (team,match,goals,row) as 
(
select
    id_team,
    id_match,
    goals,
    ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by match_id order by team_id)
from table_game
)

select 
t1.date_of_match,c.team, c.goals, c1.goals, c1.team, t1.city
from cte c
left join cte c1 on c.match = c1.match and c1.row = 2
inner join table_matches t1 on c.match = t1.id_match
where c.row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_of_match, g1.id_team team1, g1.goals goals1, 
       g2.goals goals2, g2.id_team team2, m.city
  from matches m  
  join games g1 on g1.id_match = m.id_match
  join games g2 on g1.id_match = m.id_match and g2.id > g1.id
```

---

test:

```
with games(id, id_team, id_match, goals) as (
         select 1, 'GER', 1234, 7 from dual union all
         select 2, 'BRA', 1234, 1 from dual),
     matches(id_match, date_of_match, city) as (
         select 1234, date '2014-07-08', 'Belo Horizonte' from dual)
select date_of_match, g1.id_team team1, g1.goals goals1, 
       g2.goals goals2, g2.id_team team2, m.city
  from matches m  
  join games g1 on g1.id_match = m.id_match
  join games g2 on g1.id_match = m.id_match and g2.id > g1.id
```

result:

```
DATE_OF_MATCH TEAM1   GOALS1 GOALS2 ID_TEAM CITY
------------- ------- ------ ------ ------- --------------------
2014-07-08    GER          7      1 BRA     Belo Horizonte
```